# Unable to get access token from instagram

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, instagram, laravel-5.1, instagram-api

Im using this [instagram wrapper package](https://github.com/vinkla/instagram) for [laravel 5.1](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1). Im trying to connect to instagram thorugh the API then auth a user in using

```
use Vinkla\Instagram\Facades\Instagram;
public function instagramlogin(Request $request)
{
    // Get code parameter.
    $code = $request->get('code');

    // Request the access token.
    $data = Instagram::getOAuthToken($code);

    // Set the access token with $data object.
    Instagram::setAccessToken($data);

    // We're done here - how easy was that, it just works!
    Instagram::getUserLikes();
    // This example is simple, and there are far more methods available.
}
```

and then be able to get access to his/her profile data. but I keep getting an error stating

```
ErrorException in Instagram.php line 526:
Undefined property: stdClass::$access_token
```

How do I auth a user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. You basically have to use the [cosenary instagram package](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API) as this package is a wrapper for that package. So if you run through the documentation on the cosenary package and use facades instead, the functions will work.